# Questions for Regulus

Tags: grammar-identification, translation-explanation, perfect-tense, french, future-tense

I am recently trying to read *Regulus*, the Latin version of *the Little Prince* translated by Augusto Haury, and I met some problems in Chapter 4. It may be somewhat troublesome to make several threads so I put them in this single post for the moment.

Latin text:

> Ergo etiam hac de causa pyxidem pigmentorum **graphidasque** emi. [...] Conabor equidem imagines ipsius quam simillimas exprimere, sed **non satis exploratum habeo** id mihi prospere processurum esse. [...] Itaque modo haec, modo illa tempto, utcumque **successura** sunt.

Original French text:

> C'est donc pour ça encore que j'ai acheté un boîte de couleurs et **des crayons**. [...] J'essayerais, bien sûr, de faire des portraits le plus ressemblants possible. Mais **je ne suis pas tout à fait** certain de réussir. [...] Alors je tâtonne comme ci et comme ça, **tant bien que mal**.

English version by Katherine Woods:

> It is for that purpose, again, that I have bought a box of paints and **some pencils**. [...] I shall certainly try to make my portraits as true to life as possible. But I am not at all sure of success. [...] So I fumble along as best I can, **now good, now bad, and I hope generally fair-to-middling**.

- What is the strange word **graphida**? By translingual comparison, this word is certainly for a pencil (*crayon* in French), but I find this word in almost no dictionary. Only DuCange gives **graphida** in a very late usage, as the synonym of **scriba**, a scribe. Is there any reason for Haury to use this word? In most part of his text, he tends toward a quite classical Latinity, for example, he uses **volucris machina** for an airplane, instead of a Neo-Latin word like **aeroplanum**, and he in fact, uses **miniatura cerula** for a colored pencil in Chapter 1. I have no idea why he uses this weird noun. (If it's worth a further discussion, I will split this to another post.)
- What is the grammatical structure of the **non satis ...** part? Does **habere** + *perf. ptcp.* mean the same as a regular perfect tense?
- What does **successura sunt** mean? Why future periphrasis? (The English version seems saying something different from the French, and the Latin version is much more paraphrased.)

Comment: The English translation certainly captures the sense, but reverses the modifiers. The French literally means "So I fumble around thus and thus, [doing] well as often as poorly." Whereas Woods has put the "good/bad" first and the "so-so" second. (And of course inserted "as best I can" and "I hope generally" to glue the parts together, I think a little gratuitously.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll address each question in order:

## Translation of "pencil"

Regarding the translation of "pencil" (French: "crayon"), the word is [*graphis, -idis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgraphis), which is a Latinization of the Greek word [*γραφίς, -ίδος*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=grafi%2Fs&la=greek&can=grafi%2Fs0&prior=gr%C4%83phis&d=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=graphis&i=1#lexicon). Though the word is rare, it seems reasonable because the usual writing implement, a [*stilus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dstilus), is quite different from a pencil.

## *Exploratum habeo*

Regarding *exploratum habeo*, *exploratum* comes (obviously) from [*exploro*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dexploro), which can mean "put to the test" (see meaning II.B). *Exploratus* is often used as an adjective meaning "ascertained" or "certain." [*Habeo*](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/habeo) can be used to mean "hold something as X" (see meaning II.D), often with a double accusative. See, for instance, an almost identical construction in Cicero's *De natura deorum*, 1.51:

> ...habet exploratum fore se semper cum in maximis tum in aeternis voluptatibus.

Literal translation:

> ...he holds it as certain that he will always be in both very great and everlasting pleasures.

(Note: It's also possible to say *habere pro* + ablative.)

In the *Regulus* passage, *non satis* literally means "not enough" but could perhaps be more idiomatically translated as "not very" or--as in the French--"pas tout à fait."

Putting it all together, we could translate literally:

> I do not hold is as very certain that it will turn out successfully for me.

## *Successura*

The Latin translation isn't very literal here: "In whatever way they follow on one another." As for the future periphrasis, I'm not sure why the translator opted for that construction, but [Livy](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=successur+%5BLiv%5D) certainly seems to use a similar construction, so it has attestations.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

[1] For *graphida*, you would have had to recognize the classic 3rd declension ending -is, -idis, which is common among words of Greek origin. That makes the word in question [graphis](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DG%3Aentry+group%3D15%3Aentry%3Dgraphis), which can mean a type of sketching pencil, same as it does [in Greek](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dgrafi%2Fs). The final -as indicates that it's accusative plural, which is the ending (-ας) for 3rd declension nouns in Greek.

[2] *Exploratum* can mean "sure" or "certain" (hence *explorate*, "for sure, certainly"), and *non satis habeo* means "I think it is insufficient", so perhaps what is meant is "I think it is insufficiently certain" = "I am uncertain".

[3] The future participle [regularly is used](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/future-participle) in periphrasis. With *utcumque* especially it gives the air of possibility, "however they might succeed." [Lewis and Short](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dutcumque) actually provide an example of this usage from Tacitus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't ever noticed this -as form so I considered it a regular -a declension word.